# Docker PHP-FPM: tmp directory grows very fast

Tags: php, docker, size, tmp

I have a problem. I use PHP-FPM docker (php:8.0-fpm). After 2 days, I have found that the tmp directory is very big: 20.1 GB. And it still grows.

The Problem is, that my server has a storage only 30 GB :(

Do you know,

- is it normal, that tmp directory grows very fast?
- how can I limit the tmp directory size?

[image: Size of TMP directory]

Comment: This sounds like an application specific problem, PHP is not writing temp files on its own. What application are you running?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Symfony 5.4. I cannot find any information about symfony and tmp-files :( I have found, that the opcache can write in tmp-folder. But the opcache.max_file_size is set to 2MB (2097152), aber all of files in /tmp are bigger.

Comment: well, symfony on its own is not an application but a framework. Did you write your own code? Does it write temp files somewhere? This would be my best guess.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that no. I don't save any files :(